# Uploading a large file to OneDrive shared folder issue (createUploadSession error)

Tags: rest, api, onedrive

Although Microsoft official documentation quite rich, I can't find any details of how exactly I should upload the **large file** to a ***shared*** folder (not to my drive).

I've followed the docs:

```
POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession

{"Item":{"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior":"replace","name":"20200310-155252-700.jpg"}}
```

Where the itemId is the folder id I am trying to upload that file to.

However, it returns 400 Bad Request error `Name from path does not match name from body` message.

But the request path provided *in docs doesn't expect passing the file name* at all!

I kind of suspecting that the itemId should be an existing item on the drive (not even inside the folder), rather than a folder id to create that file in, but a) I am not sure about that and b) how is it possible to have an empty file without any content before having that upload complete (again, if I am right about b)).

Am I at least following a right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because poorly updated OneDrive Api official documentation Microsoft has.

A correct url must be as follows:

`$"{baseUrl}/drives/{drive}/items/{itemId}:/{fileName}:/createUploadSession"`